# Spark DataFrame created from JavaRDD<Row> copies all columns data into first column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame which I need to convert into `JavaRDD<Row>` and back to DataFrame I have the following code

```
DataFrame sourceFrame = hiveContext.read().format("orc").load("/path/to/orc/file");
//I do order by in above sourceFrame and then I convert it into JavaRDD
JavaRDD<Row> modifiedRDD = sourceFrame.toJavaRDD().map(new Function<Row,Row>({
    public Row call(Row row) throws Exception {
       if(row != null) {
           //updated row by creating new Row
           return RowFactory.create(updateRow);
       }
      return null;
});
//now I convert above JavaRDD<Row> into DataFrame using the following
DataFrame modifiedFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(modifiedRDD,schema);
```

`sourceFrame` and `modifiedFrame` schema is same when I call `sourceFrame.show()` output is expected I see every column has corresponding values and no column is empty but when I call `modifiedFrame.show()` I see all the columns values gets merged into first column value for e.g. assume source DataFrame has 3 column as shown below

```
_col1    _col2    _col3
 ABC       10      DEF
 GHI       20      JKL
```

When I print modifiedFrame which I converted from JavaRDD it shows in the following order

```
_col1        _col2      _col3
ABC,10,DEF
GHI,20,JKL
```

As shown above all the _col1 has all the values and _col2 and _col3 is empty. I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: what is your updateRow variable exactly?

Comment: I update Row by converting Row object into java collection list of objects and then updating one field value and then returning that list as part of RowFactory.create

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I mentioned in question's comment ;

It might occurs because of giving list as a one parameter.

```
return RowFactory.create(updateRow);
```

When investigated Apache Spark docs and source codes ; In that [specifying schema example](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema) They assign parameters one by one for all columns respectively. Just investigate the some source code roughly [RowFactory.java](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3c0156899dc1ec1f7dfe6d7c8af47fa6dc7d00bf/sql/catalyst/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/sql/RowFactory.java) class and GenericRow class doesn't allocate that one parameter. So Try to give parameters respectively for row's column's.

```
return RowFactory.create(updateRow.get(0),updateRow.get(1),updateRow.get(2)); // List Example
```

You may try to convert your list to array and then pass as a parameter.

```
YourObject[] updatedRowArray= new YourObject[updateRow.size()];
updateRow.toArray(updatedRowArray);
return RowFactory.create(updatedRowArray);
```

By the way RowFactory.create() method is creating Row objects. [In Apache Spark documentation about Row object and RowFactory.create() method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html);

> Represents one row of output from a relational operator. Allows both generic access by ordinal, which will incur boxing overhead for
> primitives, as well as native primitive access. It is invalid to use
> the native primitive interface to retrieve a value that is null,
> instead a user must check isNullAt before attempting to retrieve a
> value that might be null.
>
> To create a new Row, use RowFactory.create() in Java or Row.apply() in
> Scala.
>
> A Row object can be constructed by providing field values. Example:
>
> import org.apache.spark.sql._
>
> // Create a Row from values.
>
> Row(value1, value2, value3, ...)
>
> // Create a Row from a Seq of values.
>
> Row.fromSeq(Seq(value1, value2, ...))

According to documentation; You can also apply your own required algorithm to seperate rows columns while creating Row objects respectively. But i think converting list to array and pass parameter as an array will work for you(I couldn't try please post your feedbacks, thanks).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Actually I have 45 fields/columns for simplicity I showed only three columns. Row Factory.create() takes variable argument so it accepts list java will it make any difference if I pass all values by hand

Comment: Hi, I have just improved the answer in respect of your requirement.

Comment: Hi thanks much it worked converting List<Object> int array.